# influxdb v2 transformed as a service

Tags: influxdb-2, nssm

We did use nssm.exe to transform our existing influx database into a database running 24/24.

Since we did that, we encounter the following issue.
At first start of the service, influx as started as if it was the first time we used it --> we had to reconfigure all our buckets/tokens/...

We still have in the folder " c:\Users<username>. influxdb\data\ " our previous DB but i don't know how to recover them and transfer the data (with their dedicated bucket) into the "new" influx running as a service.

Does anyone can help me to recover data from influx working before being transformed as a sevice?

Usually when i want to transfer data from a DB of one influx into the DB of another, i use :
"influx inspect export-lp --bucket-id "xxx" -- engine-path "XXX" --output-path ./export.lp " and i push the LP file into my other influx afterwards.

In this case i don't find any way to do that.

I have tried to just copy the whole folder like to the desired bucket in "c:\Users<username>. influxdb\data\ " and copy it into "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.influxdbv2\engine\data"
but it does not work like that.

I am not fully familiar with coding/scripting, as well as with the really specific language use in programming/gestion of DB/...

I try to learn with video on internet but at the moment i am stuck.

Thank you in advance,
Simon